# Dynamic field and method injection in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp

From https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection#Considerations:

> Be aware that injected values are dynamic: values that are changed in the context may be immediately propagated into injected fields/methods. Also, we have the "@Optional" annotation which allows values not currently in the context to be injected as "null" and re-injected later when the values are added to the context.

I wonder how is dynamic injection implemented in Eclipse RCP, so it remains universally thread-safe and whether there is a deterministic decision making process with RCP for figuring out what may not be injected via constructor (into a final field).

Comment: I haven't seen anything about thread safety and the code is very complex so it is hard to say. There is quite  substantial memory overhead when using tracked injection (lots of `ContextInjectionListener` objects) so constructor injection is probably preferable for things that don't change.